# There is a deadlock here in the code but i can't find it

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm learning socket programming and here i divide receive part in other tread. When some object of client's class turn his state to "STATE_ONLINE" the DEADLOCK comes and the strangest part is that every next "clients[i]" locks.

```
    //infinite loop 
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_CLIENT_NUMBER_THREAD; i++) {
        auto lockGuard = clients[i]->try_lock_guard();
        cout << "fd_set creation try " << i << endl;
        if (lockGuard->owns_lock()) {
            cout << "fd_set creation owns "<< i << endl;
            try {
                if (clients[i]->isState(STATE_ONLINE)) {
                    int sd = (int)clients[i]->getSocket();
                    if (sd > 0) {
                        cout << "adding " << i << " to fd_set" << endl;
                        FD_SET(sd, &readfds);
                    }
                    if (sd > max_sd)
                        max_sd = sd + 1;
                }
            }
            catch (...) {
                cout << "fd_set exception" << endl;
            }
        }
        delete lockGuard;
    }

    activity = select(max_sd, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    //code
```

This code is in infinite loop.

Here I'm using lock guard so i can lock the client object, handle it and then unlock it while "delete lockGuard" comes.

**client.h** parts:

```
class client{
    std::mutex _lock;
    SOCKET socket;
    STATE state;
public:
    int id;
    using mutex_type = std::mutex;
    using u_lock = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

    u_lock* lock_guard();
    u_lock* try_lock_guard();
    SOCKET getSocket();
    bool isState(STATE state);
```

**client.cpp** parts:

```
client::u_lock* client::lock_guard() { 
    return new u_lock(_lock); 
}

client::u_lock* client::try_lock_guard() {
    std::cout << "trying locking" << std::endl;
    return new u_lock(_lock, std::try_to_lock);
}

SOCKET client::getSocket() {
    return socket;
}

bool client::isState(STATE state) {
    return ((this->state & state) != 0);
}
```

output when someone connects to the server and turns state of 0's client to "STATE_ONLINE":

```
fd_set creation try 0
fd_set creation owns 0
adding 0 to fd_set
trying locking
fd_set creation try 1
fd_set creation owns 1
trying locking
fd_set creation try 2
fd_set creation owns 2
trying locking
fd_set creation try 3
fd_set creation owns 3
trying locking
fd_set creation try 4
fd_set creation owns 4
trying locking
fd_set creation try 5
fd_set creation owns 5
trying locking
fd_set creation try 6
fd_set creation owns 6
trying locking
fd_set creation try 7
fd_set creation owns 7
trying locking
fd_set creation try 8
fd_set creation owns 8
trying locking
fd_set creation try 9
fd_set creation owns 9
trying locking
fd_set creation try 10
fd_set creation owns 10
trying locking
fd_set creation try 11
fd_set creation owns 11
trying locking
fd_set creation try 12
fd_set creation owns 12
trying locking
fd_set creation try 13
fd_set creation owns 13
trying locking
fd_set creation try 14
fd_set creation owns 14
trying locking
fd_set creation try 15
fd_set creation owns 15
trying locking
fd_set creation try 16
fd_set creation owns 16
trying locking
fd_set creation try 17
fd_set creation owns 17
trying locking
fd_set creation try 18
fd_set creation owns 18
trying locking
fd_set creation try 19
fd_set creation owns 19
trying locking
fd_set creation try 20
fd_set creation owns 20
trying locking
fd_set creation try 21
fd_set creation owns 21
trying locking
fd_set creation try 22
fd_set creation owns 22
trying locking
fd_set creation try 23
fd_set creation owns 23
trying locking
fd_set creation try 24
fd_set creation owns 24
trying locking
fd_set creation try 25
fd_set creation owns 25
trying locking
fd_set creation try 26
fd_set creation owns 26
trying locking
fd_set creation try 27
fd_set creation owns 27
trying locking
fd_set creation try 28
fd_set creation owns 28
trying locking
fd_set creation try 29
fd_set creation owns 29

//and nothing else, but it should write that infinitely
```

I tried to wrap whole thing in try-catch but it didn't work.

Comment: FYI the entire point of a lock guard is that you don't need to remember to `unlock`, even if your function ends due to an exception. It avoids leaking a lock. But by returning a raw owning pointer to one, you've reintroduced the problem, but requiring the user to `delete` it instead of `unlock` the mutex. They are RAII objects and should always be returned by value.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find out where each thread is blocked? Most debugger let you inspect each thread's callstack. When you get your deadlock, you can go through the threads and it should be clear which threads are blocked and by which functions.

Comment: How can it be infinite? The loop reaches `DEFAULT_CLIENT_NUMBER_THREAD` and finishes. Is `DEFAULT_CLIENT_NUMBER_THREAD` 30?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I use lock guard because i need a wrapper that can return a mutex from an object. So i can change object without locking the mutex on each method.

Comment: @273K All that code is in infinite loop I just didn't show that :) Yes DEFAULT_CLIENT_NUMBER_THREAD is 30

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your comment. Thats my first question on Stackoverflow I didn't read that "How to Ask", so sorry for my carelessness.

Answer (score 0):

**select()** function takes 5 parameters and the last one is a pointer to **timeval** struct, that **select()** function uses to read for that time period. If that pointer is NULL (like in my example) it reads infinitely.

So there is no a deadlock i thought it was.